# How can I do the javascript animations for the navigation tabs like in the example below

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

How can I do the animations for the navigation buttons like in the site below?
http://cdn.livedemo00.template-help.com:82/wt_39902/#!/pageSplash

Some pseudo-code would be really helpful also.

Comment: Why don't you just check out how they implemented it?

Comment: browser -> "save as..." and see for yourself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to first think of it as two separated parts...
two parts that are being animated from the same place (probably angular directive\jquery function)
if you want to learn more about css animation  is would suggest :
https://css-tricks.com/

this is assuming you would want to control this by classes

if you would want to do it via js i would recommend angular or simple jquery if you aren't familiar with angularjs....